# Find sectors in a racing line.

Tags: geometry, artificial-intelligence

Consider the following photo:

*To magnify image, right click and select **open-image in new tab** or something similar*

[image]

The photo above is a random race circuit data I've collected. What I'm trying to do is find the *corner entry*, and *corner exit*. The *path* in the middle would be known as *sector*. The corner entry and exits are labelled in green in the following image,

[image]

(Note where they are position in the road is the job of my AI algorithm thus for this, we are placing these entry and exit points in the middle). The following are the observations I made for the entry/exist points:

- entry have close to zero slope and then a change of slope.
- exit have changing slopes before it until a point with zero slopes is hit.
- For corners with "S" like formation, the inflection point is both an entry/exit point.

Also we are ignoring z-axis.

My plan so far is the following:

1. take the first derivative of each point via parametric derivative, $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}$.
2. From (1), I will take the vertices that have the last 0 slope prior to change of slope (indicating corner entry).
3. From (1), I will take the vertices that is the first 0 slope after a sequence of non-zero slope, indicating corner exit.

(Note that the first derivative also takes in inflection points, since inflection points have 0 slope).

**Problem:**

My plan seems to not work and places corner exit and entry in wrong places (e.g. lump in straight aways). Considering that corner entry often have gentle slopes, this sometimes doesn't place the entry point until we are deep in the corner (which is bad). I've been debugging this problem for quite a while so before I go on I have two main questions:

1. If my idea is right (or close to right), could it be that my implementation is wrong?
2. If you have a better method of finding *corner sectors*, can you share it with me?

**Edit:**

I thank both answers. My level is too low to thumbs up so I have to use prng to select one answer. Anyway, the program is working perfectly. The following is the line graph generated by curvature along the circuit:

[image]

Basically, the local minimums corresponds to straight-away. It even captures the big irregular hairpin with smaller straight away. One could even incorporate filtering to avoid the noise. Again, I thank all of the answers.

Comment: Can you give a precise definition of where the corner entries and exits should be? I think you're saying they should be before and after sharp turns, but what qualifies as sharp?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Just to begin, I didn't mention sharp turn. To be honest, I have a hard time formalizing that. This is probably because "straight lines" tend to become corners when maximum possible speed increases since the ai agent will now treat them as a state to be dealt with. In other words, I'll just look at the ideas given below and figure the definition of corner later since it seems like an ai problem. Also, I've driven so much that I just see these things automatically and I don't know how my brain does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a useful quantity for you would be there [curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature) of your racetrack, which measures how sharp you are turning. If you a parameterization $x(t),y(t)$ of your racetrack, the curvature at the point $(x(t),y(t))$ is
$$
\kappa(t)=\frac{x'y''-x''y'}{(x'^2+y'^2)^{3/2}}
$$
Note this can be negative. I believe positive curvature means you're turning left, negative right.

Then, to find the entry/exit points, choose some value $\kappa_0$, and let the entry points be the points $(x(t),y(t))$ where $|\kappa(t)|$ goes from being beneath $\kappa_0$ to above it, and the exit points the opposite, where $|\kappa(t)|$ is above $\kappa_0$, and dips below. The idea is that the regions between entry and exit points will be regions of high (specifically, $>\kappa_0$) curvature. Playing with the value of $\kappa_0$ should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If your curve is parameterized by length, the curvature is the absolute value of the second derivative of the curve with respect to the length, so you want to watch the value of 
$$
\sqrt{({d^2y\over dt^2})^2+({d^2x\over dt^2})^2}
$$
and start the curves at the point which this value changes.

This assumes that the tangent vector has unit length, i.e.
$$
({dy\over dt})^2+({dx\over dt})^2=1
$$

Reference: Do Carmo *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces* section 1.5.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I will definitely look in to it.